# Invalid azure URL or Personal Access Token in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTxDL.jpg)I am using SonarQube 8.9 LTS community edition, while configuring the azure devops server withSonarQube it is throwing error as invalid azure URL or PAT, I had tried multiple PAT's with defferent pat permissions.
The

Invalid azure URL or Personal Access Token in SonarQube